# Using QGIS to remove portions of polygons that overlap in same layer?

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features

Is there a way to easily eliminate the overlapping portions of polygons in the same layer?

For example, I want to turn this

[image]

into this

[image]

I used Union to break the polygons apart where they overlapped, and then used Delete Duplicate Geometries to get rid of half the overlaps, but still had to manually delete the others. That's fine for the example, but won't work with the large amount of polygons that will be in the real data.

Comment: Thank you for including "before" and "after" images of what you're trying to achieve. It made your question easy to understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

QGIS Processing Toolbox has a SAGA **Polygon self-intersection** tool (under `SAGA | Vector polygon tools`).

It works much like QIGS Union Tool, while this tool retains only one feature per the overlapped area.

Open the attribute table of generated `Intersection` layer and <s>select</s> **Delete** all features whose `fid` (or `id`) is `0`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the Symmetrical Difference tool.

[image]

> **Symmetrical difference**
>
> This algorithm extracts the portions of features from both the Input and Overlay layers that do not overlap. Overlapping areas between the two layers are removed. The attribute table of the Symmetrical Difference layer contains original attributes from both the Input and Difference layers.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But does this only work if they are in different layers? When I tried it, I got a blank layer. All the overlapping features will be in the same layer.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another workaround with QGIS built-in functions:

- [Intersect](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#qgisintersection) the *polygons* layer against itself.

The output is an *Intersection* layer with all the geometries of the *polygons* layer and new geometries for their overlapped areas.

- [Select by location](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisselectbylocation) the geometries of the *Intersection* layer than are **equal** (parameter) to *polygons* layer geometries, and [Delete](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=editing#deleting-selected-features) them.

The output is, in the same *Intersection* layer, two or more geometries for any overlap in the *polygons* layer.

- Make the [Difference](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#qgisdifference) between the *polygons* layer and the edited *Intersection* layer.

The output is a new *Difference* layer, with the geometries of the *polygons* layer without the overlapped areas.